# iOS-iOS device real time sound transfering

Tags: audio, data-transfer

I'd like to know if there's any way I could connect two iOS devices to transfer sound in real time. Sort of a walkie-talkie device. Anyone would know any apps for that?

Thanks :)

Comment: The phone app? ;)

Comment: I'd like one that could transfer more easily adressed, quickly and preferably free.

Comment: Skype then, but I assume what you're looking for here is PushToTalk.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, I think the key phrase to search for here would be Push-To-Talk (PTT). Take a look at the following:

[Push to talk apps](http://readwrite.com/2012/05/23/5-push-to-talk-apps-that-turn-your-smartphone-into-a-walkie-talkie)